# Data Science/Engineering (Dev/Prod) Environment

Tags: google-cloud-platform, data-science, environment, production

I am going to create environments. For now i have gcp machine and i run jupyter in there. Everytime, i need start it, and with 3 people it is hard to work in same environment. I know, there is docker, jupyter hub, but did not find and suitable roadmap to create dev/prod environment.

My aim to create dev and production environment. Everything should be on GCP.

Any suggested path ?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can take a look at the [best practices for enterprise organizations](https://cloud.google.com/docs/enterprise/best-practices-for-enterprise-organizations). In order to properly split resources it's often advised to use different projects. However, depending on the GCP product, you could also use versions, such as with App Engine (see [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26331324/best-practice-for-production-and-test-environments-in-google-app-engin)).

Comment: Thanks for link, also i need a roadmap of the processes. Run a jupyter hub on docker? Or install all of them alone ?

Comment: In order for the community to better help you it would be great if you could narrow down the issue with specific and reproducible errors. This forum is not intended to provide a roadmap or to perform a development for you. The aim of your question doesn't seem definite and therefore doesn't fit Stack Overflow requirements. You will find more information on how to ask good questions in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Please, feel free to rephrase your problem providing further information and trying to narrow down the issue so that we can better help you.