# Handling cron jobs on staging environment on google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, cron, staging

I want to set up a staging environment on Google App Engine and have found good guidance for this in the following question: [How to set up a staging environment on Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793860/how-to-set-up-a-staging-environment-on-google-app-engine)

The only unanswered question I have is how to handle Cron jobs in this case. Ideally I'll just have to change the version to deploy to production, however I fear that that would mean that all cron jobs also run on the staging version, or is this not the case?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a different version approach you need to pay attention to [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron#Python_app_yaml_Cron_and_app_versions):

> If the **target** parameter has been set for a job, the request is
>   sent to the specified version. Otherwise Cron requests are sent to the
>   default version of the application.

I've been using the `target` parameter to direct cron jobs to different modules, based on the quote above I *guess* it could be used to direct jobs to different versions as well, using [module routing via URL](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/routing#routing_via_url), probably something like this:

```
  target: version
```

or

```
  target: version-dot-module
```

Personally I prefer a different application approach to ensure no interference between the staging and the production environments, even when performing massive re-works breaking backwards compatibility :)

As for the method, I use 2 different workspaces from 2 different branches of the code, which have minimal differences between them (the `application` fields in the `.yaml` files and maybe other staging-related deltas):

- a `staging` workspace & branch
- a `production` workspace & branch

Whenever I'm happy with the code in the `staging` branch I:

- merge the `staging` branch in the `production` one
- update the `production` workspace and deploy from it -> updating the `production` app
- disable whatever I need in the `staging` workspace (committing the changes to the `staging` branch as well if so desired)
- deploy from the `staging` workspace -> updating the `staging` app

Probably the method would be usable in a different version approach as well, the `version` fields in the `.yaml` files being different in the 2 branches.