# Google App Engine upgrading part by part

Tags: google-app-engine, ab-testing, gae-module

I have a complex appengine service that was written in PHP, now I want to migrate it to Python part by part.

Let's say that my service has 2 parts: `/signIn/....` and `/data/...`. I just want to migrate `/signIn/` part first, then `/data/` later.

However, since my service is big, so I want to build new `/signIn/` part in Python, then use [Traffic Splitting](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/developers-console/#traffic-splitting) to make some A/B Testing on this part.

My problem is that Traffic Splitting can be applied on versions only, so my old and new versions have to be in same module, *and same module means that they have to written in same language (I was wrong here, see updated part)*. But I am migrating from PHP to Python.

What is the best solution for me?

Thanks,

**Solution**

With Dan Cornilescu's helping, this is what I do:

1. Split the app into 2 modules: default and old-version.
2. Dispatch `/signIn/` into default module, the rest to old-version module.
3. Make another version of `/signIn/` (*default module*) in Python
4. Configure Traffic Splitting to slowly increase requests percent into Python part. This will allow us to test and make sure there is no serious bug happen.

Note:
The `/signIn/` part must be default module, since GAE's traffic splitting works at default module only.

I confirmed that we can make 2 versions in different language for a module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach is to split your PHP app in modules in a 1st step. It's not a completely wasted effort, most of that will be needed anyways to just allow your app to work in multiple modules, not related to the language change. I suspect this is actually why you can't use A/B testing - mismatch between the modules. Unavoidable.

Once the split in modules is done then you can go on with your 2nd step - switching the language for selected module(s), with A/B testing as you intended.

A more brave approach is to mix the 2 and write the `/signin/` module directly in python. On the PHP side you'd just remove the `/signin/` portion (part of the earlier mentioned 1st step). Should work pretty well as long as you're careful to only use app language independent means for inter-module communication/operation: request paths, cookies, datastore/memcache keys, etc. A good module split would almost certainly ensure that.

You have testing options other than A/B, like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33760403/4495081.

You can also have the new code/module able to serve the same requests as the old one, side-by-side/simultaneously and using a `dispatch.yaml` file to finely control which module actually serves which requests. This may allow a very focused migration, potentially offering higher testing confidence.

I'm also not entirely sure you can't actually have 2 versions of the same module in different languages - the versions should be pretty standalone instances, each serving their own requests in their own way using, at the lowest layer, the language-independent GAE infra services. AFAIK nothing stops a **complete** app re-write and deployment, with the same version or not - I've done that when learning GAE. But I didn't switch languages, it's true. I'd give it a try, but I don't have time to learn a new language right now :)

Comment: I have just checked yesterday, WE CAN MAKE 2 VERSIONS IN DIFFERENT LANGUAGES.

Comment: Thank you, I figured it out. However, I need to keep '/signIn/' part in both PHP and Python, and about 50% of request will be directed to PHP parts, the rest is to Python. I can remove the PHP part only when I sure that Python part are compatible and does not have any error.