# How does App Engine work with git and branches?

Tags: git, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a conceptual question regarding App Engine. Let's say my code is in a Git repo and I want it to run on App Engine (GAE).

From what I can see in the tutorials, I clone my repo in the Cloud Shell, run the commands to create a new instance, and I get my app running in GAE with it's own subdomain. Any administration after this can be done via the GUI.

Is this correct?

After this, is there any way to automate that this GAE engine instance always update and run the latest code in master when I commit to the master branch (or any other branch)?

Can I chose the subdomain name I get? What if I want a production server with code in `master` branch, and a dev server with the code from the `dev` branch?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is correct.

An instance will only run the version of the code it corresponds to. But automated deployments (launching new instances with the newer code) are possible, for example by wrapping `google app deploy` commands inside a CI/CD solution triggered by commits to the respective branch. See, for example, [Continuous integration/deployment/delivery on Google App Engine, too risky?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40192557/continuous-integration-deployment-delivery-on-google-app-engine-too-risky/40193364#40193364) 
Another option may be [via the Admin API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/deploying-overview) (I didn't try it).

You can always use a custom (sub)domain of your liking, see [Mapping Custom Domains](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains).

Yes, separate per-branch deployment environments are possible, see:

- [How to use GAE's dispatch.yaml with multiple development environments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46016022/how-to-use-gaes-dispatch-yaml-with-multiple-development-environments?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Advantages of implementing CI/CD environments at GAE project/app level vs service/module level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43218971/advantages-of-implementing-ci-cd-environments-at-gae-project-app-level-vs-servic)