# Google App Engine routing with dispatch.yaml

Tags: google-app-engine, url-routing, google-app-engine-python

I try to deploy a web app on my sandbox GCP project where there is already an app deployed. So I'm trying to play with the path to have the two web apps deployed at the same time.

My dispatch looks like this

```
dispatch:

- url: "*/wc/api/.*"
  service: wc-api

- url: "*/wc/.*"
  service: wc-front


- url: "*/.*"
  service: default
```

When I do so, all my calls to mysandbox.appspot.com/wc/ gets redirected to my `default` service and I don't understand why (I can see the calls in the logs of the `default` service).

If this helps, here is the `app.yaml` of my `wc-front` service.

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes
service: wc-front

default_expiration: "10m"

handlers:
- url: /wc/.*
  script: app.APP
  login: required
  secure: always
```

Do you see any error in this ?

(Calling directly wc-front-dot-mysandbox.appspot.com/wc/ returns the typical App Engine 404 error)

Thanks

Comment: I am facing the same issue. I want to route "*/api/*" to backend service and "*/api/model/*" to model service. I wrote the dispatch.yaml to do so even keeping the model service routing at the top but still all the load is going to backend service

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears the problem was coming from the `.*` notation. This should only be used for the very general `*/.*` rule.

My new - working - dispatch

```
dispatch:

- url: "*/wc/api/*"
  service: wc-api

- url: "*/wc/*"
  service: wc-front


- url: "*/.*"
  service: default
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, indeed, you need to configure your `dispatch.yaml` file, for App Engine to route your application based on the URL that you set there. It seems that your `service: default` it's getting all URLs and redirecting them to the service set there.

Considering that, I would recommend you to take a look at the official documentation about configuring the `dispatch.yaml` file - you can get some better ideas on how to configure it - and this other post from the Community, where another user has a similar use case as yours, that I believe should help you.

- [dispatch.yaml Configuration File](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/reference/dispatch-yaml)
- [How to use GAE's dispatch.yaml with multiple development environments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46016022/how-to-use-gaes-dispatch-yaml-with-multiple-development-environments)

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: hello, my dispatch is in my post. Anything wrong with it ? Thanks

Comment: Hi @ValentinCoudert By checking your `dispatch.yaml` file, it seems that your logic on `- url: "*/.*"  service: default` it making every call that has a `/` to go to the `default` service. Could you please give it a try removing this or changing it?